# Представление html-селектора для JS

Tags: javascript, html, консоль

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<a id="test"></a>
        <script>
        var test = $('#test');
        console.log(test);
        console.log(test[0]);       
        </script>
```

Запрашиваю содержимое селектора test два раза, во втором случае с индексом 0. На картинке то, что выдала консоль. Как называется этот "феномен" - html-формат получить можно, только присвоив индекс (или это не индекс?), и что за представление в первом случае?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В певрвом случае это jquery-объект, с ним можно работать с помощью методов библиотеки `jquery`, например `$('#test').offset().top`.
Во втором случае это нативный `js`, который можно было бы получить так `document.querySelector('#test')`, с этом объектом можно так же работать, но с помощью нативных методов `js`, например `document.querySelector('#test').getBoundingClientRect()`.

Также эти объекты можно конвертировать между собой, например так:

```
var js, jq;
jq = $('#test');
js = jq[0];
js = jq.get(0);

js = document.getQuerySelector('#test');
jq = $(js);
```

Comment: А где можно почитать про вот это конвертирование js = jq[0];
js = jq.get(0); Не нахожу в гугле, так чтобы серьезные источники... Изучила бы эту тему основательно.

Comment: Ну это не то, чтоб прям конвертирование и это необходимо раз в пятилетку. Это по сути просто извлечение нативного js-элемента из объекта jquery. Метод описан в официальной документации https://api.jquery.com/get/